# How to change mode of buffer created by with-help-window

Tags: help-mode

I have a buffer with name `*fsharp info*` which I want to change (programmatically) the mode from `help-mode` to my custom mode.

I created a simple major mode `fsharp-info-mode` to highlight `fsharp` documentation using `markdown`'s font-lock.

```
(define-derived-mode fsharp-info-mode help-mode "fsharp-info-mode"
  "major mode for fsharp info."
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(markdown-mode-font-lock-keywords)))
```

With no success, I tried to enable it to the buffer with name `*fsharp info*` using

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\*fsharp info\\*" . fsharp-info-mode))
```

Looking in `fsharp-mode`, I discovered that the use `with-help-window` to create `*fsharp info*`.  In the documentation, it says that `help-mode` is activate in the buffer (maybe that is why I can't change?)

**EDIT:**

I solved my problem temporarily advising `fsharp-ac/show-info-window` which is the function called by `fsharp-mode` to display the documentation.

```
(defadvice fsharp-ac/show-info-window (after fsharp-ac/show-info-window-after activate)
  (save-excursion
    (switch-to-buffer "*fsharp info*")
    (fsharp-info-mode)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe or provide a link to information about `fsharp-mode`. But if that mode (what buffer(s) is it used in?) creates a buffer `*fsharp-info*` and puts it in `help-mode` then presumably that's the mode it should be in, no?

You can add a function to `help-mode-hook` that changes the major mode, if you like. The function would check that the buffer name is, say, `*fsharp-info*`, and if so then it would invoke your `fsharp-info-mode` instead of `help-mode`.

I'm guessing that's not a great idea, and there is likely a good reason `fsharp-mode` puts the buffer in `help-mode`.

Another possibility is to define a *minor mode*, and have a `help-mode-hook` function turn that on in buffer `*fsharp-info*`. In that case the major mode would still be `help-mode`, but your `fsharp-info-mode` would be a minor mode, active at the same time.

Comment: I liked the idea of creating a minor mode for that.  I've never done but and it sounds as a good opportunity.